# Upgrading from lessc 1.75 to lessc 2.2.0 removes ace styles?

Tags: css, less, ace-editor

So I have a web app that uses less to generate css and i recently upgraded from lessc 1.75 to lessc 2.2.0.

In doing so, I see that lessc has some optimizations like replacing hex colors with actual color names.

Unfortunately for me, I see that the main.css that gets generated now is removing a bunch of styles that I think ACE needs.

Specifically, the entire tables.less seems to be completely excluded now 
despite being imported from the ace.less via:

```
@import "tables.less";
```

I see no errors so I am not sure what is going on. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Some links? I have no idea where can I get these `ace.less` and `table.less` you mentioned to test.

Comment: its not free unfortunately:

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR

Comment: I see. Well, either way there's no any major breaking changes in Less v2. So if something does not work it's most likely some code that abuses certain bugs/issues (that were fixed in v2).